# How to set break point at line number correctly in gdb?

Tags: debugging, gdb

Refer the code below with line numbers with it.

```
1     void f(string& s){
...
          //some code
...
12        for(unsigned int i = 0; i <= end; i++){
13            unsigned int a = s[i] - 'a' + 1;
14            unsigned int b = s[end-i] - 'a' + 1;
15        }
16    }
```

In gdb, I have to check the value of variable `b`. How do I set breakpoints here correctly. I know that breakpoint has to be after line `14`. But, whenever I type line 15, `b 15`, it adds breakpoint at line 16.
Can somebody please help ?

Comment: In real life code there should be more statements after line `14` where you can set breakpoint. In your example `b` is unused so it does not make much sense.

Comment: @ks1322 Yes there is more code to it. I get your point, if there is a useful variable, then it must have been declared before the end/outside the loop in which case the value can be checked at the start of loop. I was just curious to know if it is possible to set breakpoint in such a situation.

Comment: I don't know of any debuggers that let you specify a breakpoint that is *after* a specific statement. Try these things with gdb: set a breakpoint at the beginning of the line, and then either type `next` (and examine the variable if it's still in scope at the next line) or type `watch b` followed by `continue`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure on the reason, but a similar thing happens in Visual Studio when setting breakpoints, which makes me think it's a commonplace thing.

My cheap way of getting past this would be adding a line after your equation that says something like:

```
b = b;
```

Then setting a breakpoint there

Comment: Thanks man. Actually there is more code to it. I was just curious to know if such a break point can be set.